# changing style of part of Textarea

Tags: html, angular, typescript, textarea

I created a comment component in Angular. I also created a mention user component and when I type @ sign it shows me all users and I can select one of them. Now after the user is selected I want to change the color of user name to blue.

Unfortunately, I saw that this is not possible with Textarea. I can not simply change the Innerhtml of Textarea. One option that I have is to use a single line input field. I saw that many big web sites like LinkedIn or Instagram also have a single line input. But I saw that Facebook has multi line Textarea. I made some research and found out that in Facebook it is not a Textarea but a customized reach text.

How can I have a multi line input where I can change the color style of part of the text?

Comment: Please provide code you've tried, and/or a minimal reproducible example. We can't really help you if you don't have code.